# Custom Session State Management using DynamoDB

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to implement a custom session management on DynamoDb.

My current MVC application is maintaining state within the application and I would like to use outproc and move it DynamoDb.

1. Do I have to write a custom provider and do it?
2. Is there a standard way of achieving this ?

Comment: If one does not exist already you need to write your own. Possible sample - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178588(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: Alexei thanks, Well i know how to write a custom provider, I wanted to know is there a standard way of doing that

Comment: way of doing what? Custom providers infrastructure is the way to use arbitrary storage for ASP.Net session state... I'm not sure what kind of standard you are looking for...

Comment: Alexei please look at the answer i just found over the web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I found

http://www.nudoq.org/#!/Packages/ViPRDataServicesSDK/EMC.ViPR.DataServices.AWSSDK.SessionProvider/Amazon.SessionProvider

What needs to be done is change the mode to Custom and implement a custom provider

For the custom provider u can use the AWS Provider already implimented

https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/tree/master/AWS.Extensions

Hope this helps someone !!

Comment: I know this is an old question/answer but the aws github link 404's

Comment: @GiovanniB Looks like the repository is no more there! Sorry about that